# Перебор свойств объекта в объекте(если правильно выразился)

Tags: javascript

Есть объект, в котором также находится еще один объект. Возможно ли (на примерах) перебрать все их свойства сразу?

Answer (score 4):

Можно написать простую рекурсивную функцию

```js
let obj1 = {
  field1: "hi",
  field2: 11,
  filed3: {
    "filed3-1": true,
  }
}

function goRec(obj) {
  for (let key in obj) {
    let value = obj[key];
    
    // делаем то что хотим с ключём и значением
    console.log(`key: ${key}, value: ${value}`);
    
    // определяем объект
    if (typeof value == "object") {
    
      // работаем рекурсивно
      goRec(value);
    }
  }
}

goRec(obj1);
```

Comment: @HovhannesShaxulyan если какой-то из ответов вас устраивает, просто отметьте его галочкой (вверху слева у ответа) как верный

Comment: чисто информативно, `for (let key in obj)` будет перебирать как свойства самого обьекта, так и его прототипа. Не говорю что это ошибка, просто нюанс :)

Comment: Гораздо понятней для меня вот так....   var someObject = {name: "someName", surname: "someSurname", age: "someAge", family: {father: "Name", mother: "Name", brother: "Name"} }  for (var keys in someObject) { var family = someObject[keys]; if (someObject[keys] != "object" {document.write(someObject[keys]} else {for (var keys2 in family) {document.write(family[keys2]);

Answer (score 2):

Можно сделать так :

```js
var o1 = {
  o2: {
    q2: 1,
    w2: 2
  },
  q: 1,
  w: 1
}

iterate(o1);

function iterate(obj) {
  Object.keys(obj).forEach(p => {
    if (typeof obj[p] == 'object') {
      console.log(`${p} is object`);
      // если значение свойства обьект, вызываем для него функцию iterate(рекурсия)
      iterate(obj[p]);
    } else {
      console.log(p);
    }
  });
};
```

Comment: Только изучаю.... Возможно попроще с for..in?

Comment: @HovhannesShaxulyan ну или надо просто разобраться и понять что и так не сложно :) да и с `for...in` есть уже ответ, так-что мой будет, просто как альтернативный пример :)

Answer (score 2):

В данном случае попробуйте использовать рекурсию:

```
function recursive(obj) {
    for(let key in obj) {
        if(typeof obj[key] === 'object') {
            recursive(obj[key])
        } else {
            //что то делаем с объектом obj[key]
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `if(typeof key === 'object') {` вы ключ проверяете на объект, а надо значение

Comment: Вы верно говорите, поспешил видимо. Исправил.

Comment: И всё ещё ошибка будет в вашем коде

Comment: Попробуйте снипет использовать, там можно сразу код проверить, очень удобно.

Comment: Спасибо за уточнения)

Comment: честно говоря, когда мои ответы "критикуют", у меня возникает непринятие и неприятное ощущение, и тяжело на это реагирую, видимо тяжело признать, принять ошибку у меня пока, а вы так правильно и позитивно среагировали, ловите мой +

Comment: Спасибо) я просто "критику" воспринимаю как повод улучшить что то в своих знаниях, устранить, так сказать, возникшие в них пробелы.

Comment: Здоровый подход.